# Hardware Schematic For Connecting Vibration Sensor to MSP430

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, adc, msp430, vibration

I have a [MiniSense 100 Vibration Sensor](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Flex/MiniSense_100.pdf) with me, which I am trying to interface with my MSP430 Launchpad to track the vibrations of refrigerator compressor. However, I am not sure if connecting it directly to my Launchpad, can damage the MSP Board.

When I tried to research on my own, I came across there different suggestions, such as [this one](https://forum.43oh.com/uploads/monthly_10_2010/post-122-135135492434.png) v/s [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/216274/arduino-piezo-vibration-measurement-circuit?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) v/s [this one](http://www.theorycircuit.com/piezo-vibration-monitoring-sensor-arduino/).

MSP430 has 3.3v operating voltage. In the third one, the guy has directly fed the pin to ADC pin of Arduino. Will doing this damage the MSP430 Dev Board? What schematic should I follow?

I had to ask this question because, I couldn't risk damaging the board. I'm completely newbie to designing schematics. Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: The second option seems to be the better one from my perspective. As you say you don't want to risk damaging your board, putting a 3.3 TVS zener in parallel will protect your input from any overvoltage

Comment: TVS diode and zener are two different things. Zeners are much slower than TVS and with that 1 MOhm resistor the 3.3 V zener diode won't start to conduct at 3.3 volt

Comment: And if you want go get the amplitude of the oscillation, adding source resistance( or impedance) will make the reading lower than reality.

Comment: @LongPham Umm. do you mean that by adding any kind of circuitry I would be altering the analog input to my microcontroller and I shouldn't be doing it? If yes, then should I just connect the two parts? Won't it damage the MCU? I have to measure/track the acceleration values

Comment: No, personally, I would prefer to buffer it with an opamp + DC bias circuitry because it has very high input impedance. but for simplicity, the circuit which Dorian provided would sufficient.

Comment: One more question, are you going to sample and analyze the signal or you need just as a vibration detector above a threshold?

Comment: I want to monitor the vibration of the HVAC compressors over time, for fault detection patterns@Dorian

Comment: @Doherty An accelerometer might be more appropriate for this task as I see the graphics from Sparkfun. The vibration sensor bandwidth is verry low, arround 50 Hz and adds some parasitic vibration due it's own resonant frequency (the fast oscillations you can see on the graphic). It's also one axis sensitive so the readings will be dependent on the sensor placement. I know that an accelerometer requires an additional SPI port but gives accurate readings, you might want to look at this product or similar: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/mma8452q-accelerometer-breakout-hookup-guide

Comment: I tried using an accelerometer (MPU-6050) earlier. But with 3 different axis, I wasn't able to come to any conclusion. The data was very confusing. So, I am hoping to interface and test with one axis before jumping to 3 axis.@Dorian

Comment: @Doherty but this sensor is just as ignoring two axis and adding some extra noise. It's true, some extra vecotor computation and substraction of G acceleration is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The one without any protection is really bad.

The other two have a major flaw, both are asymmetrical. Remember, the sensor has a capacitive output.

This will make the signal analysis a nightmare, let's take the first example with a short 2V peak to peak sinusoidal burst. Before the burst the voltage is zero, then a sinusoidal signal with the lower peak aligned to -0.6V (the forward voltage of the zenner diode) then after the burst a 1.4V (the average voltage of the output signal) slowly decreasing to zero signal.

You can see in the picture a 30Hz 1.5V 20ms burst (VI1) and the output after the clipper (VO1) The zenner diode forward conducting is raises the output signal adding a DC bias.

The other two are a 50Hz 300mV 20ms burst and the output after the clipper, identical but also with negative values that ADC cannot read.

[image]

Even with a lower than 0.6V signal, you can read only the positive voltages which is a drawback for asymmetrical shakings like a bump.

I would use a setup like this with two clipping diodes and two resistors that add a constant DC bias to make the entire range readable by ADC:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo00bp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for explanation. If I am not mistaken, then R3 drops the voltage, while R1 and R2 are used a voltage divider. D2 seems to be eliminating negative part. Not sure sure how d1 and C2 affect the circuitry. Could you please share the specs of the diode D1 and D2 I should use for 3.3 v Launchpad? Also, I am curious, that will adding this circuitry, reduce or alter my readings? since, I can't find the max voltage that can come out of the sensor, I have no idea how to calculate values for voltage dividers etc.

Comment: Sorry,but could you also, please help me analyse this schematic by sparkfun? https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/piezo-vibration-sensor-hookup-guide
I am amazed if Sparkfun made a mistake.

Comment: R3 is only for current limitation when D1 or D2 opens, can be lowered down to 100 ohm if you have noise. D1 and D2 is better to be schottky diodes like BAT 41 that have a lower forward voltage because at least with D2 there is an ESD diode in parallel inside your chip that we dont want to open when clipping.

Comment: R1 and R2 are making the DC bias, when no signal from the piezo sensor the ADC input voltage will be half of the above VDD. I hope you understand , that line you should connect to a voltage, if you use ADC reference voltage you will use the maximum ADC range since the steady voltage at the ADC input will be at the half of the maximum. D2 limits the voltages above VDD. C2 is a decoupling capacitor, you might already have one on the board, is for cutting the current spikes to VDD

Comment: @Doherty I wouldn't bet to much on Sparkfun's design, as you see their signal is also  limited to -0.6V after connecting to Arduino board even after "dumping" that means that the negative currents ar still dangerously going through the ESD protection diode inside chip. The eqiuvalent impedance for my circuit would be 0.5 M ohm, if their measurement are accurate this will bring the voltage to approx 2.5 V max, appropriate for ADC range.

Comment: Hmm, the datasheet says that the sensor may be modelled as a voltage source in series with a capacitor.

Comment: Actually, ATMEL themself have provided a App Note showing that we can detect zero crossing (AC mains)  with a 1 Meg resistor in series with a digital input.

Comment: @Doherty Sparkfun is for amateur enthusiasts, simple things not more. Their 1Mohm resistor does nothing for protection, rather a resistor in series like R3 in the above schematic it cuts high current spikes that can damage the chip.

Comment: I see some stupid conclusion of the Sparkfun's editor after putting 1M resistor and connecting to Arduino: "The voltages spike between -0.5 and +5V are safely within the tolerable range of the ATmega328’s I/O pins". Actually the the clipping diodes form the chip are "guilty" of the -0.5V and I could clearly see also two spikes above 5V that certainly go through the upper diode inside chip.

Comment: In fact anything connected to an Arduino input will be "between -0.5 and +5V, safely within the tolerable range" before it fries the chip.